# Accidentally deleted an answer

Tags: support

I was writing today a comment to an answer to a question. Shortly after posting, I realized that my comment was complete blunder. I wanted to delete my comment - there was a small "delete" link near the place where the comment is placed -, but what happened was, that the whole answer was deleted!!!!

Now I would like to know:

- Is there a way to un-delete it?
- What would be the correct way to erase a comment? Or should I just post another comment saying "please ignore my previous comment"?

For the time being, I wrote an answer to the question, where I apologized for what I did, tried to recreated the erased answer, and refered to the original author of this answer.

This is the topic where it happened:

[How to check shell script has enough permissions to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296567/how-to-check-shell-script-has-enough-permissions-to-run)

Comment: You would not be able to delete an answer by someone else all by yourself. Chances is that it was deleted by the answer OP or possibly a moderator around the same time.

Comment: Imagine that you could just delete answers willy-nilly. The site wouldn't be much of use if that were possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer's OP has deleted it.

It's got nothing to do with your actions (except as a possible response to your comment).

Comment: This would be a pity, because I think the OPs answer was a good one. Is there a way I can send him or her a message? I don't find a contact information on the profile page, http://stackoverflow.com/users/3775049/edwardramsey

Comment: If the OP chose to not share any contact information then that's how it goes.